# Change Grid Loading Message

Tags: extjs, grid, store

I'm using Extjs 4.2.1,  and i just want to change all LOADING message from my grids.

What should i do?  I had read something about mask, but in other version(Extjs 3.0).

Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried `loadMask`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want all grids to display this new loading message (ones that are already created and all ones you will create in the future), you should override the main gridview class like this using the loadingText property:

```
Ext.define("NameDoesntMatterView", {
    override: "Ext.grid.View",
    loadingText: "I'm loading or something..."
});
```

If you only want it on a single grid, use the viewConfig:

```
var myGrid = Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
    viewConfig: {
        loadingText: "I'm loading or something..."
    }
});
```